# AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, AbsoluteToNanoseconds): symbol not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, installation, conda

I'm trying to run 'conda install something' on macOS Mojave but i'm getting this error at every turn:

```
conda install update
```

This is the entire traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 149, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ._vendor.auxlib.entity import EntityEncoder
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/entity.py", line 253, in <module>
    from .collection import AttrDict, frozendict, make_immutable
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/collection.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .compat import isiterable, iteritems, odict, text_type
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/compat.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._vendor.five import WhateverIO as StringIO, with_metaclass
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/_vendor/five.py", line 80, in <module>
    absolute_to_nanoseconds = CoreServices.AbsoluteToNanoseconds
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 379, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 384, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, AbsoluteToNanoseconds): symbol not found
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar error happened to me on macOS Big Sur and removing miniconda2 and installing miniconda3 worked for me.

I followed the instructions on https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html which is basically:

```
rm -rf ~/miniconda2
rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh # after downloading the installable
```